# Steel material looks fake

Tags: rendering, materials, light

I created a model and applied a steel material. I have a background HDRI images, but, I don't think it's reflecting the same way that real steel does. What should I change? The ground material reflects the HDR, but the model does not seem to be as shiny as real steel.

[image]

Comment: Is this using Blender internal or Blender Cycles?

Comment: Blender cycles.

Comment: First thought is it looks very grainy. Could try considerably upping the number of render samples.

Comment: Reduce glossy roughness.

Comment: It doesn't really look like there's an HDR.. The floor is washed out a bit and lacks different colors of reflection. Maybe that's why steel doesn't reflect too.